# TCPDF is not showing Unicode from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, unicode, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF class for generate pdf report from my php file. There is a table which contain unicode. In normal PHP file when I set meta charset=utf-8 then it show my desired unicode language. But in PDF it does not show. I have tried following code:

```
new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_general_ci'");
```

But nothing work for me. Its always show - à¦¬à¦¾à¦‚à¦²à¦¾ , this kind of string like my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue using [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/). It's quite easy to use compared to TCPDF.

Comment: Link updated. Try now. If not working then directly go https://mpdf.github.io/